# Change the language of an Ubuntu Touch app

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, ubuntu-sdk

In my Ubuntu Touch app I need to be able to change the language of the app without rebooting the app or the device. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this using gettext (the internationalization technology the Ubuntu SDK uses).

You might be able to do it using the native Qt internationalization framework.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In some desktop apps like goldenDict it is possible through the options. How do they do that ? The same way can't be done in Ubuntu Touch ?

Comment: In Ubuntu Touch the language is set globally in the Settings app, and it cannot be changed on-the-fly or on a single app basis. While we'll probably have to look into changing languages on-the-fly at some point, I don't think there will be support added for changing it on a single application basis (e.g. Android does not do that, either). Looking at goldenDict, they use the native Qt internationalization framework as mentioned on the final comment of the answer (https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/tree/master/locale). It might be worth rethinking whether your app really needs the feature